# Generation random (positive and negative) numbers for a quiz

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am writing a Math Quiz app for my daughter in xcode/swift.
Specifically, I want to produce a question that will contain at least one negative number to be added or subtracted against a second randomly generated number.
*Cannot be two positive numbers.*

i.e.

> What is (-45) subtract 12?
>   What is 23 Minus (-34)?

I am struggling to get the syntax right to generate the numbers, then decide if the said number will be a negative or positive.

Then the second issue is randomizing if the problem is to be addition or subtraction.

Comment: To be clear, which combinations of numbers do you want ? Any combination `a + b` such that either `a<0` or `b<0` ?

Comment: Yes.    Basically a numberA a random from -50 to 50 in range, NumberB the same.  But, if two positive numbers are generated, then one must be switched to negative (NumberB = NumberB *-1)

Comment: sorry, my comment kept sending for no reason ;)

Comment: Alright, I'll write you something up quickly. Very nice that you're making this for your daughter :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to solve this without repeated number drawing. The idea is to:

1. Draw a random number, positive or negative
2. If the number is negative: Draw another number from the same range and return the pair.
3. If the number is positive: Draw the second number from a range constrained to negative numbers.

Here's the implementation:

```
extension CountableClosedRange where Bound : SignedInteger {

    /// A property that returns a random element from the range.
    var random: Bound {
        return Bound(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(count.toIntMax())).toIntMax()) + lowerBound
    }

    /// A pair of random elements where always one element is negative.
    var randomPair: (Bound, Bound) {
        let first = random
        if first >= 0 {
            return (first, (self.lowerBound ... -1).random)
        }
        return (first, random)
    }
}
```

Now you can just write...

```
let pair = (-10 ... 100).randomPair
```

... and get a random tuple where one element is guaranteed to be negative.

Comment: That's quite a neat approach. I like it.

Comment: Voted up on both these styles.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my attempt. Try running this in a playground, it should hopefully get you the result you want. I hope I've made something clean enough...

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import Cocoa


let range = Range(uncheckedBounds: (-50, 50))

func generateRandomCouple() -> (a: Int, b: Int) {
    // This function will generate a pair of random integers
    // (a, b) such that at least a or b is negative.

    var first, second: Int

    repeat {
        first   = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(range.upperBound - range.lowerBound))) - range.upperBound
        second  = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(range.upperBound - range.lowerBound))) - range.upperBound
    }
        while (first > 0 && second > 0);

    // Essentially this loops until at least one of the two is less than zero.

    return (first, second)
}


let couple = generateRandomCouple();
print("What is \(couple.a) + (\(couple.b))")
// at this point, either of the variables is negative


// I don't think you can do it in the playground, but here you would read
// her input and the expected answer would, naturally, be:

print(couple.a + couple.b)
```

In any case, feel free to ask for clarifications. Good luck !

Comment: Ah man. Thank you. I'll slot this into my code and make the required changes. Didn't even consider cocoa.

Comment: Much appreciated. Peace.

Comment: @ElephantBoy Cocoa isn't available on iOS, but only Foundation is needed (for `arc4random`).

Comment: @NobodyNada indeed, I wrote this on the Mac but this does not need Cocoa.
Do accept the answer and upvote when you're satisfied ;)

Comment: If first or second is equal to zero then the loop will break leaving none of the candidates less than zero! Changing the while condition to (first >= 0 && second >= 0) will produce at least one candidate less than zero. It still could result in both candidates being less than zero however.

Comment: @Bamsworld absolutely! Thanks for the catch.

Comment: Cheers people. 

Comment: let couple = generateRandomCouple();
print("What is \(couple.a) + (\(couple.b))")
// at this point, either of the variables is negative

Comment: DARN! Excuse post above.  This worked a charm.  Many thanks.  My next issues will be creating a random to decide if the sum is an addition or a subtraction.  I was considering using arc4random_uniform(1) // Basically generate a 1 or 0 value.  Then a case or for loop that will pop up a question type (add or subtract) based on the 1 or 0 resultant.        var addMe: Int = 1  var takeMe: Int = 0.  To set the vars up.  Is there a n=more efficient way to do this?  I can't think of anyway round it other than using a randomizer/loop check.

Comment: This is what I have to ensure we get a random sum type.

Comment: // This ensures we don't get two positive numbers.  At least one will be negativegative.  It checks and changes the +/- where required.

if NegativeOne == NegativeTwo {
    numberOne = numberOne * -1
}; numberTwo = numberTwo * -1